# problem when comparing string in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I have this code:

```
switch (cpf) {
      case this.aluno.cpf.length == 0:
        this.cpfVazio = true;
      break;

      case this.aluno.cpf.length != 14:
        this.cpfVazio = true;
      break;
      default:
        this.cpfVazio = false;
      break;
    }
```

this.aluno.cpf is a string.
And it is not comparing always going to default.
Does anyone know what is wrong?

Here is the HTML code and the class Aluno:

```
<ion-item>
        <ion-label position="floating">CPF*</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="aluno.cpf" [brmasker]="{mask: '000.000.000-00', len:14, type:'num'}" (ionBlur)="validaCpf(aluno.cpf)" (ionChange)="validaCpf(aluno.cpf)" name="cpf" required></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
      <small class="mensagem-erro" *ngIf="cpfVazio" name="cpf">Este campo é obrigatório!</small><br>

export class Aluno {
    inscricao = "";
    dataInscricao = "";
    nome = "";
    dataNascimento = "";
    cpf = "";
    endereco = "";
    cidade = "";
    bairro = "";
    cep = "";
    contatos = "";
    email = "";
    facebook = "";
    igreja = "";
    soube = "";
    proposito = "";
    historico = "";
}
```

Comment: Do not use a `switch` but several `if`.

Comment: That's not how switch statement works.

Comment: you are using switch statement incorrectly,

Comment: What are you actually trying to validate, because maybe `minLength` and `maxLength` of 14 would be easier?

Comment: I want to be sure this.aluno.cpf is equal 14 characters

Answer (score 1):

For your use case it's better to use an `if/else` statement. It's way cleaner and easy to reason about.

On the other hand, your switch statement is a bit weird. If you want to use `cpf`'s length then you have to include it in the switch statement like `switch (cpf.length) { ... }` and then in your `case` use something like `case 0: do something`. It will also work with an expression but it's not a pretty solution. Use `if/else` instead.

Comment: Thx it didn't work with an expression but it worked when I put (cpf.length) and case 0: it worked! dont know why it didnt work the other way!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
if (this.aluno.cpf.length !== 14) {
  this.cpfVazio = true;
} else {
  this.cpfVazio = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thx all!
It didn't work with an expression but it worked when I put (cpf.length) and case 0: it worked! dont know why it didnt work the other way!

Maybe if I put like this:
´´´
case cpf.length == 0:
´´´
It would work, because I wasnt using the cpf variable inside the switch!